# I cannot get the "checked" option of a Radio Box to set when looping through options in my Blazor .RAZOR page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am populating a group of radio buttons from a `Dictionary<String,String>` and I want the first option checked by default when the page loads. However, the things I am trying are not working.

This is a Bootstrap modal window within a component on this .RAZOR page.

The first time I open the modal, the correct [first option] is selected. However, whenever I open it subsequent times, the last option is always selected.

```
// in class StringConstants:
public static Dictionary<String, String> COLOR_EXAMPLES = new Dictionary<String, String>()
{
    {"red","The color of a fire truck"},
    {"orange","The color of a carrot"},
    {"yellow","The color of a banana"},
    {"green","The color of grass"},
    {"blue","The color of the sky"},
    {"indigo","The color of blueberries"},
    {"violet","The color of an eggplant"}
};

// in the .RAZOR file
<div>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in StringConstants.COLOR_EXAMPLES)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="theinput-@entry.Key" @(firstOptionExpended ? "checked" : "">
            <!-- OR -->
            <input type="radio" id="theinput-@entry.Key" checked='@firstOptionExpended ? "checked" : ""'>
            <label for="theinput-@entry.Key">@entry.Value</label>
        </div>
        firstOptionExpended = true;
    }
</div>

@code {
    bool firstOptionExpended = false;

    // I also tried this

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        firstOptionExpended = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an epiphany, I came up with an answer that worked for me.

```
<div>
    @{
        bool firstOptionEnabled = true;
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in StringConstants.COLOR_EXAMPLES)
        {
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="theinput" id="theinput-@entry.Key" checked="@(firstOptionEnabled)">
                <label for="theinput-@entry.Key">@entry.Value</label>
            </div>
            firstOptionExpended = false;
        }
    }
</div>
```

This is also with assistance from [@Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2286743/marius)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few flaws in your code that you will need to correct.

Firstly, when applying an attribute to en element in Blazor, and the attribute is something like `checked` that can be assumed as true when no value is supplied, must be supplied like this:

`<input type="checkbox" checked=@(IsChecked) />`

Secondly, when doing inline if starting with `@(`, close that inline if with `)`. In your case this: `@(firstOptionExpended ? "checked" : ""`
Should be: `@(firstOptionExpended ? "checked" : "")`

Thirdly, a radio button group must be named:
`<input type="radio" name="theName" />`

Here is a working example:

```
@page "/"

<div>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> entry in COLOR_EXAMPLES)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="theinput-@entry.Key" name="SelectColor" checked="@(!firstOpetionSelected)">
            <label for="theinput-@entry.Key">@entry.Value</label>
        </div>
        firstOpetionSelected = true;
    }
</div>

@code {
    bool firstOpetionSelected = false;

    public static Dictionary<String, String> COLOR_EXAMPLES = new Dictionary<String, String>()
    {
        {"red","The color of a fire truck"},
        {"orange","The color of a carrot"},
        {"yellow","The color of a banana"},
        {"green","The color of grass"},
        {"blue","The color of the sky"},
        {"indigo","The color of blueberries"},
        {"violet","The color of an eggplant"}
    };
}
```